# Linq Unable To Cast Issue

Tags: c#, linq, casting

When I try to run

`InvTotal = g.Sum(d => d.Field<double>("Total")) < 0 ? "W" : "N"`, I get a

`Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.String'` error.

How do I need to change the code for it it compile successfully.

Comment: the type of `InvTotal` is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you need correct parenthesis.

```
var InvTotal = (g.Sum(d => d.Field<double>("Total")) < 0) ? "W" : "N"
```

Without them the compiler will compile `0 ? "W" : "N"` first, and the result of that will be used in the comparison.

Sometimes, the C# compiler needs a little help if it comes to the ? operator.

Comment: Parenthesis isn't a issue. Look at operators precedence [C# Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

what is the type of InvTotal? I'm guessing it is currently a Double. Should work if you change the type to String, or remove the declaration of InvTotal and change your line to "var InvTotal = g.Sum..."

Answer (score 0):

I think that in this case it's no problem with parenthesis.

Problem is with type of `InvTotal`, if you write `var InvTotal =....` everything will be ok.

Explanation to Maarten answer:

In C# we can not write something like that:

```
int x = 2;
var tmp = x ? "W" : "N";
```

If we try, we will get following error:

> Error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'"

C# is not C++ where zero indicates false and nonzero values indicates true.

So you can write something like that:

```
g.Sum(d => d.Field<double>("Total")) < 0 ? "W" : "N"
```

you can also have multiple logic operators without parenthesis in first section of ternary operator:

```
g.Sum(d => d.Field<double>("Total")) < 0 && 1 == 1 && 2 != 4 && 9 != 0 ? "W" : "N";
```

Comment: If you do not know the type of InvTotal, then how do you explain the exception which says that a double cannot be converted to a string? Since if the ? operator works it should result in a string, since that is the resulting type of the ? operator.

Comment: It's hard to explain because @user1936588 didn't tell us about type of `InvTotal`, but how I showed you, you need not use parenthesis. So I think that @user1936588 can try your solution with parenthesis without var keyword, and we will see if parenthesis are necessary. Btw, it's interesting question :)